# Pandas DataFrame (TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot)

Tags: python, csv, plot, dataframe

I'm trying to learn how to use pandas and im trying to display a plot showing the total births by sex & year.

[1] [https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Vz7.png] (Cant figure out why there's another column called sex

but this image above the data im trying to plot

and keep getting TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot)

This is what my code looks like

[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbZmM.png

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because during the pivot the dataFrame becomes multi-indexed. There are no columns with values to plot against eachother. You can use `df.reset_index()` to set the multiple indexes as columns, and then plot their values.